# F2084 compiler error with generics and implements in delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, interface, delphi-10-seattle

I am working with a third party library. One of their components uses a structure that has a generic base class that descends from TInterfacedObject. They descend from that generic as a regular class, providing the necessary type. If I try to use that class in an `implements` then I get a `F2084 Internal Error: AV0AE194EC-R00000000-0` compiler error.

Here is some sample code to paste into a console application.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

type
  ITestIntf = Interface
    ['{78910A8A-0FE0-473F-A199-3CD10BFC6295}']
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  // The generic base class
  TGenericBase<T: TComponent> = class(TInterfacedObject)
  private
    FObject: T;
  public
    constructor Create(AObject: T); virtual;
  end;

  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  end;

  // The descendant class that implements our interface
  TAdapter = class(TGenericBase<TMyComponent>, ITestIntf)
  public
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  TProxyObject = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestIntf)
  strict private
    FMyAdapter: TAdapter;
  public
    property MyAdapter: TAdapter read FMyAdapter implements ITestIntf;
  end;

constructor TGenericBase<T>.Create(AObject: T);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FObject := AObject;
end;

procedure TAdapter.DoSomething;
begin
  // Not really doing anything
end;
```

I am guessing that this is a bug with the compiler. If I change the base class to a simple class that inherits from TInterfacedObject then the code compiles fine. The error is happening in the 32-bit and 64-bit compilers.

Is this a compiler error?

Comment: Have had no problem to compile your code in Tokyo. Just to say..

Comment: @Victoria Thanks, that means it's more than likely a compiler bug that's been fixed. I can work around it for now and we are switching to Tokyo in the next couple of months.

Comment: Thats an ICE, they are always compiler defects. Submit a bug report.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Does it make sense to submit a bug report if it's already been fixed in the latest version?

Comment: Yes, because then somebody else can find it and know the solution. Or they might patch old versions like they said they would. Did they ever?

Comment: Then again, nobody would hold it against you if you just found a workaround to your problem and got on with your life.

Comment: Already reported and fixed since 10.1 https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12671